# Restart Program When Ping Timesout Twice

Tags: python

Is there a way to do a constant ping in the background and restart an application when the pings return "Request Timeout" more than twice?

We have a problem with wireless and when the connection times out it freezes out telnet sessions on our handheld scanners.

What I currently have is cobbled from other posts:

```
import os
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen([r"C:\tester.exe"])

hostname = "google.com"
response = os.system("ping -n 1 " + hostname)

if response == 0:
    print (hostname, 'is up!')
else:
    print (hostname, 'is down!')
    os.system("taskkill /im tester.exe")
```

This works about as good as it looks since I have never coded before....

Comment: Note that ``subprocess.Popen`` produces an actual object that you can capture and use to kill the process. You can also use ``Popen`` to handle output. There is generally no need to use ``os.system``.

Comment: I will look at taking out the os.system lines and replacing them with Popen. Would that be all I need to do to make the switch? Just change os to Popen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never worked with subprocess before and my code is solely based on the assumption that your posted code works.

You could try:

```
import os
import subprocess
import time

def start_subprocess():
    subprocess.Popen([r"C:\tester.exe"])

 hostname = "google.com"
 start_subprocess()

while True:
    response = os.system("ping -n 1 " + hostname)
    if response == 0:
        print (hostname, ' is up!')
        time.sleep(2)
    else:
        response = os.system("ping -n 1 " + hostname)
        if response == 0:
            print(hostname, ' is up AGAIN')
        else:
            print (hostname, ' is down!')
            os.system("taskkill /im tester.exe")
            time.sleep(2)
            start_subprocess()
```

This will start the subprocess and go into an infinite loop where it pings every 2 seconds for a response.
If the response is negative, it will check for another response. If there is no response again, it kills the process, waits for 2 seconds and restarts `tester.exe`.

Comment: This is a huge step forward! Thank you.

I edited the sleep time to 4 just to make sure we don't have a false positive disconnect due to slow connection being a possible factor.

Comment: Yeah, was not sure about the 2 seconds there but I did not know how time sensitive the program in the subprocess would be.